# WatchOS crashes, how to debug?

Tags: xcode, debugging

On the simulator, the app extension works fine, but in some actual devices, it seems to be crashing on launch.

I can't reproduce it myself, so all I have to go by are the crash reports from Xcode:

[image: Crash report from Xcode]

> Combine: type metadata completion function for Published.Storage

I'm not importing Combine into the project, but I do use environment objects, observable objects, state properties, etc.

How can I find more about what is causing the crashes from this? When I click on "Open in project...", it doesn't point to any lines of code.